# 2009 Ford Fusion Tail Lights Outs

Tags: tail-lights

The tail lights are not working, but the brake lights and all other lights  are working fine. I checked the fuses, they're all fine, but I could not find the relative relay. I changed the bulbs and found out I had the wrong bulbs in prior to changing, and one filament was burnt out in each bulb. However, the new bulbs did not fix the problem.

It does look like there is some disconnected wires in the trunk, but I believe they may be for a trailer connection or something else, only because there are several wires disconnected, but all the other lights are still working. There is one suspicious wire that leads to both sides of the trunk, but the wires going directly to the bulbs look Ok and in place. I cannot find any info that I could understand explaining the wiring to follow.

Thank you in advance for any help. The bulb sockets look a bit dark near where the bulb connects, but I can't tell if it's burnt, and I doubt that would happen to both or be the cause for both tail lights going out.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a serviceable relay for the tail lights, all exterior light controls are built into the Smart Junction Box. If your license plate lights and rear side marker lamps work, than take a look at your connectors again and see if you have power and ground. Make sure the bulbs fit snuggly and make contact with the terminals in the connector.

All the rear lights share a common power wire and ground. The ground location should be in the center of the trunk near the latch or striker. If you don't have power follow the gray/yellow wire back to the splice.

Answer (score 1):

Also, make sure you are using the correct bulb - you mention two filaments as it is possible to "force" a single filament (indicator /reverse) bulb into the socket.